# Identifying green prickly branches plant

Tags: identification, houseplants, diagnosis

I am interested to know which plant(s) that is. The one with long branch falling on the ground. Its branches are prickly. The flower, I discovered that two days ago, are white with small orange dots (very nice, good surprise, hope to see more of those next year maybe). I have noticed that in the winter those long green branches become woody and die (I guess they die, but the plant, somehow is very resistant and keeps surviving without any green).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is the white stuff on the leaves a disease? Mold or else?

[image]

Also is this part of the plant, or is it a companion? You can also see the roots in the pot, very much like someone tried to do a bonsai, though I am unsure what happens.

[image]

Since last winter I am giving plant NPK and water, nothing else.

Thanks a lot. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plant with the white flowers is an *Asparagus sprengeri* fern, sometimes also the name *Asparagus densiflorus* is used. It is not a real fern but a close relative of the garden Asparagus (*Asparagus officinalis*).

It is a very easy plant to maintain, it does well in shady (low light intense) places.

The white stuff could be mold, or could be nothing. You can better cut it off just to be sure, the plant will recover from it.

The other plant is not part of it.

Comment: awesome, Thank you benn.  I hope to have this knowledge after years of gardening.

Comment: You're welcome. This plant was actually my first houseplant I got as present when I was still a student. I remember it sheds its leaves/spines when stressed, which gave me extra work in housekeeping ;-) Have fun gardening!